# Can't generate valid web. referense

Tags: java, .net, soap, web-services

I set up Open-xchage(wrote on Java) on openSUSE and installed SOAP extension on it. Then i tried to generate web referense in vs2008, but it doesn't work. Can I generate WebReferense of Java-based service and use it in .net/c# ? Any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be posible with no problems

try -> [How To: Call a Java EE Web Service from a .Net Client](http://blogs.msdn.com/bursteg/archive/2008/07/19/how-to-call-a-java-ee-web-service-from-a-net-client.aspx)

Comment: Yes i read it, but after generation i got empty Reference.cs file, so i can't do anything. Maybe it is because they used specific java types.